# How to format row if sum value of row equal specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I use excel and i have sheet look like

```
A        B            C
1        3927269      58516305
2        2356361
3        2749088
4        294545
5        13156350
6        1570908
7        1963634
8        5105449
9        3632724
10       3141815
11       7996358
12       3534542
13       29963613
14       .....
```

Now i want filter all row from 1 -> 13 and highlight  specific row only when
sum row hightlight = C1

Example :  **B2+B3+B6 = C1**

Now B2,B3,B6 highlight

I using formula  on Conditional Formatting look like:
**=SUM($B$1:B1)=$C$1**. But it not working.
How to highlight rows only sum value equal specific value ?

Comment: B2+B3+B6 <> C1 in your example. Also, what if there are more combinations that equals to C1?

Comment: @user11222393 it only my example. It can more combinations that equals to C1. It not master. If  5 row sum 1-> 13 equal C1. Select 5 row and highlight it

Comment: Because i don't know from 1 to 13 how many row or number rows sum it equal C1. I using command =SUM($B$1:B1)=$C$1 but it not highlight. I can't sum manual all row from B and compare row to C1. It very hard and has a lot time.

Comment: @user11222393 If sum value row 2,5,6,8 equal c1 highlight it. Now i must find row 2,5,6,8

Comment: B2+B5+B6+B8 also <> C1. I believe there is no combination of B1:B13 cells that equals to C1. What is the point of providing non working dataset instead of simplified example that actually have solution? Anyway, I think it is hardly if not at all possible to do it with excel formula. But you could use Excel Solver to get helper column with solution or VBA

Comment: @user11222393 I has use Excel Solver but result incorrect. It highlight but result highlight when i sum it not equal C1. I will recheck data. Thanks so much

Comment: This problem is a mathematical combinatorical one, not really programming solution. First find the math sol, and then try to resolve it.

Comment: I think we can use VBA and apply it. I think it mix math and programming

Answer (score 4):

While the question itself has an example where non of the combinations of the values listed would sum up to value in `C1`. I used a different objective to demonstrate the formula:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 3927269 | 7363629 |
| **2** | 2356361 |  |
| **3** | 2749088 |  |
| **4** | 294545 |  |
| **5** | 13156350 |  |
| **6** | 1570908 |  |
| **7** | 1963634 |  |
| **8** | 5105449 |  |
| **9** | 3632724 |  |
| **10** | 3141815 |  |
| **11** | 7996358 |  |
| **12** | 3534542 |  |
| **13** | 29963613 |  |

the formula below will show all combinations of values that sum up to the objective `C1`:

```
=LET(      objective,  C1,
               range,  B1:B13,
        combinations,  LET(i,LAMBDA(x,DROP(TEXTAFTER(REDUCE("",x,LAMBDA(combined_temp,comb,VSTACK(combined_temp,combined_temp&", "&comb))),", "),1)),i(FILTER(range,range<=objective))),
 summed_combinations,  DROP(REDUCE(0,combinations,LAMBDA(summed_temp,comb_row,VSTACK(summed_temp,SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(comb_row,", "))))),1),

FILTER(combinations,summed_combinations=objective,"no values equal the sum "&objective))
```

With given data / objective this formula returns the 3 possible combinations that lead to the sum of the objective `7363629`:
[image]

[image]

*Basically this does not answer your question (perform conditional formatting to cells used in the sum of combinations), but I figured that it would be likely that combining multiple values would soon lead to different combinations that may lead to the objective. formatting all the cells of all the combinations would not give clarity which combined values belong to the first possible combination and which to any of the next. Therefore I think this answer may be more helpful then the actual question asked.*

*For example: If we take your example of `B2+B3+B6=C1` the sum would be `6676357` (not 58516305)*

*The following combinations lead to the same sum:*

```
3927269, 2749088
2356361, 2749088, 1570908
1570908, 5105449
2749088, 294545, 3632724
1570908, 1963634, 3141815
3141815, 353454
```

Answer (score 3):

This is formula from excel Wizared on Facebook

```
=LET(
     a,A4:A16,
     i,ROWS(a),
     f,--MID(BASE(SEQUENCE(,2^i),2,i),SEQUENCE(i),1),
     IF(FILTER(f,MMULT(TOROW(a),f)=D1),a,""))
```

[image]

Comment: =TOCOL(BYCOL(LET(
a,A4:A16,
i,ROWS(a),
f,--MID(BASE(SEQUENCE(,2^i),2,i),SEQUENCE(i),1),
IF(FILTER(f,MMULT(TOROW(a),f)=D1),a,"")),LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,a))))